# copy the data from unbound dgv to bound dgv

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have two dgv, the first dgv is unbound and the second is bound. I want to copy the data in every cell to the bound dgv in order to save it. I have button but when I click it it says "Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound."

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1

        Dim rowAlreadyExist As Boolean = False
        Dim check As Boolean = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.Rows(i)

        If check = True Then
            If Sales.SalesDataGridView.Rows.Count() > 0 Then


                For j As Integer = 0 To Sales.SalesDataGridView.Rows.Count() - 1 Step +1
                    If row.Cells(0).Value.ToString() = Sales.SalesDataGridView.Rows(j).Cells(0).ToString() Then
                        rowAlreadyExist = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

                If rowAlreadyExist = False Then
                    Sales.SalesDataGridView.Rows.Add(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString(),
                                           row.Cells(1).Value.ToString(),
                                           row.Cells(2).Value.ToString(),
                                           row.Cells(3).Value.ToString(),
                                           row.Cells(4).Value)
                End If

            Else

                Sales.SalesDataGridView.Rows.Add(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString(),
                                     row.Cells(1).Value.ToString(),
                                           row.Cells(2).Value.ToString(),
                                           row.Cells(3).Value.ToString(),
                                           row.Cells(4).Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Is this VB.net ? Add correct tags

Comment: Yes sir. visual basic 2010

Comment: `Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.`  This is self explanatory.  Add the rows to the DataSource instead.